# Springboot request object validation

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, bean-validation, spring-restcontroller

I have a request object

```
public class OrderRequest {

    private List<Details> detailsList;

 }

 public class Details{
    Private String id;

    private List<Detail> detailList;

 }


  public class Detail{

    @NotNull(message = "Please provide the inventory name")
    Private String inventoryName;

    Private String inventoryId;

    Private String inventoryLoc;

 }
```

and i want to validate each request object Detail for not null or not empty.

> javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

@valid annotation is added for the controller class

> @Valid @RequestBody final OrderRequest 
>               orderRequest

but it doesn't seem to work. what am i missing here?

Comment: are you sure that you have added all dependencies?

Comment: @dehasi yes, validation-api comes in the bundled package of spring-boot-starter-web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also annotate your `OrderRequest` as follows (in case of Bean Validation 2.0):

```
public class OrderRequest {
    private List<@Valid Details> detailsList;
}
```

Or if you are using an older Bean Validation 1.1 you should place the `@Valid before the list:

```
public class OrderRequest {
    private @Valid List<Details> detailsList;
}
```