# Hibernate Validator doesn't work but I don't know why

Tags: java, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I have added some constraint annotations on the model class:

```
public class Items {
    private Integer id;

    @Size(min=1,max=30,message="${items.name.length.error}")
    private String name;

    private Float price;

    @NotNull(message="${items.createTime.isNUll}")
    private Date createTime;

    // setters and getter 
}

public class ItemsCustom extends Items {

    // add some new details

}
```

I have also set the configuration XML file:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven
    conversion-service="conversionService" validator="validator"></mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="validator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="providerClass"
        value="org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator" />
    <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:CustomValidationMessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="fileEncodings" value="utf-8" />
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="120" />
</bean>
```

And this is CustomValidationMessages.properties:

```
items.name.length.error=the length of name must be more than 1 character and less than 30 characters 
items.createTime.isNUll=the create time must be not null
```

This is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/submitItems",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitItems(@Validated ItemsCustom itemsCustom,BindingResult bindingResult) throws Exception{

    List<ObjectError> errors = bindingResult.getAllErrors(); 
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println();
        for(ObjectError e : errors) {
            System.out.println(e.getDefaultMessage());
        }
    }

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    // some process...
    return mav;
}
```

I think all is ready but it doesn't work! Anyone helps?

Comment: *but it doesn't work* - in what way? which validation doesn't work?  have you tried removing one and seeing?

Comment: @Scary Wombat Both annotations don't work and I've tried it again and again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51040451/springboot-request-object-validation?noredirect=1#comment89072249_51040451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change annotation inside controller @Validated  to @Valid

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
```